# debugging : where to find the print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have in my hands a code which I'm trying to debug. when running the code, it prints regularly `training loss : x.xxxx secs` but I can't find a line like this in the code. I need to know where it comes from. Therefore, what I would like to have is something that happens for example when there is a compilation error, it does a traceback to the last function that was called. Is it possible to do such a thing without the error ? Just printing when and in which function the printing function is called.

Comment: Your best bet is to search in your ide for the string "training loss" it looks like it'll be using string formatting

Comment: I have done that, except that this comes probably from a module and it's a lot of modules to search in.

Comment: You'll have to go down the rabbit hole then, you'll already know one entry function that eventually gets to this print so now just need to step through the code flow

Comment: You could use `sys.settrace()` to trace calls to the `print()` function, and when that's detected, check what the arguments to it are and print a traceback when it's the call you're interested in. See [Tracing a Program As It Runs](https://pymotw.com/3/sys/tracing.html#sys-tracing) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the appropriate solution or if it is an elegant solution.
I haven't tested this code when calling other module functions, but it should work.

Let me know if it helped you.

You should just add this to the top of your main function.

What it does is to redirect the print output and stop the code when the word training appears on the code. Then, you could use the pdb commands to find out where it is being printed. Pdb documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

```
import pdb
import sys
_stdout = sys.stdout


class MyStream(object):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
        self.enable_trace = True

    def __getattribute__(self, *args, **kargs):
        if args[0] in ['write', 'target', 'enable_trace']:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, args[0])
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'target').__getattribute__(*args, **kargs)

    def write(self, s):
        if self.enable_trace and ('training' in s):
            self.enable_trace = False
            pdb.set_trace()
        else:
            self.target.write(s)


sys.stdout = MyStream(sys.stdout)
print('test')
print('%s', 'training')
sys.stdout = _stdout   # return print to its old behavior
```

**EDIT:**

Changed the code a little bit, so it stops just on the first appearance, so it does not keep opening the debugger recursively. If you want to get the following appearances just set self.enable_trace to True and continue the code.